# render activeReports v8 webview in winforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webview, activereports

I was requested to migrate from v3 to v8 of active reports framework. Following the componentone ActiveReports v8 user guide, make the whole project compiles without problem. Also I can perform a successful export to .pdf.

The only problem comes with the WebView rendering, it just don't render.

I'll post the codebehind, the .aspx and the web.config

**.aspx:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CertificadoAlumno.ascx.cs" Inherits="Planeta.Modules.CampusCertificadosV8.Controls.CertificadoAlumno" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" Namespace="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web" TagPrefix="ActiveReportsWeb" %>

<ActiveReportsWeb:WebViewer ID="wvCertificado" runat="server" height="100%" width="100%" ViewerType="RawHtml"></ActiveReportsWeb:WebViewer>
```

**codebehind:**

```
public partial class CertificadoAlumno : CorePortalSubControl {
    protected GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Section.PdfExport pdfExporter;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

    public void showLoad(DAL_Certificados.CERTIFICADODataTable pdtCertificado) {
      GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport lrpt = new SectionReport();
      DAL_Certificados ldalCertificado = new DAL_Certificados();
      ldalCertificado.Merge(pdtCertificado);

      BLLCertificados lCertificados = BLLDispatcher.BllCertificados;
      if (pdtCertificado.Rows.Count > 0) {
        if (pdtCertificado[0].axis_y_key == lCertificados.C_KEY_ASIGNATURAS) {
          wvCertificado.Report = new RPTCertificadoAlumnoHorizontalInvertido();
        } else {
          if (pdtCertificado[0].col_title14.Length > 0) {
            wvCertificado.Report = new RPTCertificadoAlumnoHorizontal();
          } else {
            wvCertificado.Report = new RPTCertificadoAlumnoVertical();
          }
        }
        lrpt = wvCertificado.Report as GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport;
        setReportLogo(lrpt);//that sets the image to report

        lrpt.DataSource = ldalCertificado;//it's a DataTable
        lrpt.DataMember = ldalCertificado.CERTIFICADO.TableName;
        wvCertificado.Visible = true;
        lrpt.Run();
      }
    }
}
```

**web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="LogoffHandler*" path="Logoff.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Authentication.LogOffHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="RSSHandler" path="RSS.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Syndication.RssHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="LinkClickHandler" path="LinkClick.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileServerHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="CaptchaHandler" path="*.captcha.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.CaptchaHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="UserProfilePageHandler" path="User.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePageHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="RadProgressHandler" verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ClientDependencyHandler" verb="*" path="DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="UserProfilePicHandler" path="ProfilePic.ashx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePicHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Bring2mind Telerik Upload" path="Bring2mind.Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Bring2mind.Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadProgressHandler, Bring2mind.Telerik.RadUpload.Net2" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="SitemapHandler" path="Sitemap.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.SitemapHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
      <add name="HtmTemplateFileHandler" verb="*" path="*.htmtemplate" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.HtmTemplateFileHandler, DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.ar8" type="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.ReportBinariesStreamer, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" name="AR7_ReportBinariesStreamer" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.ActiveReport" type="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.CompiledReportHandler, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" name="AR7_CompiledReportHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.rpx" type="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.RpxHandler, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" name="AR7_RpxHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.rdl,*.rdlx" type="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.RdlxHandler, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" name="AR7_RdlxHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.ar8Web" type="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.WebCacheAccessHandler, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" name="AR7_WebCacheAccessHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/> 
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.captcha.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.CaptchaHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <add verb="*" path="LinkClick.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileServerHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <add verb="*" path="RSS.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Syndication.RssHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <add verb="*" path="Logoff.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Authentication.LogOffHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <add path="User.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePageHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add verb="*" path="DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core" />
      <add verb="*" path="DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core " />
      <add path="ProfilePic.ashx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePicHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <add path="dmxdav.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS,PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,COPY,MOVE,DELETE,MKCOL,LOCK,UNLOCK,DEBUG" type="Bring2mind.DNN.Modules.DMX.WebDAV.DavHandler, Bring2mind.DNN.Modules.DMX.WebDAV" validate="false" />
      <add path="/" verb="OPTIONS,PROPFIND" type="Bring2mind.DNN.Modules.DMX.WebDAV.DavHandler, Bring2mind.DNN.Modules.DMX.WebDAV" validate="false" />
      <add path="ComponentArtUploadProgress.axd" verb="*" type="ComponentArt.Web.UI.UploadProgressHandler, ComponentArt.Web.UI" />
      <add path="Bring2mind.Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Bring2mind.Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadProgressHandler, Bring2mind.Telerik.RadUpload.Net2" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" validate="false" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add verb="*" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" validate="true" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.ar8" type="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.ReportBinariesStreamer, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.ActiveReport" type="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.CompiledReportHandler, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.rpx" type="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.RpxHandler, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.rdl,*.rdlx" type="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.RdlxHandler, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.ar8Web" type="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.WebCacheAccessHandler, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="false" strict="false">
      <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".resx" />
        <remove extension=".resources" />
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Extensibility.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
        <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
        <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Html.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
        <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff"/>
        <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
        <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this: lrpt.Run();, 
assign the webviewer to report; this.webviewer1.Report = lrpt;  webviewer will run the report internally.